# Using VisualStateGroups to change textbox border thickness on Windows Phone 8

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to have two different border thickness values for a set of textboxes within a composite control: one for focused state, one for unfocused state. To that end, I have the following template:

```
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                <Grid Background="Transparent">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MainBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MainBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="ReadOnly">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MainBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ReadonlyBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ReadonlyBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ReadonlyBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxReadOnlyBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MainBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxEditBackgroundBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MainBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxEditBorderBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="UnfocusedBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="UnFocused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="UnfocusedBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="4" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Border x:Name="MainBorder" 
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                            BorderThickness="4" 
                            BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneDarkBorderBrush}" 
                            Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}" />
                    <Border x:Name="UnfocusedBorder" 
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                            BorderThickness="1" 
                            BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneDarkBorderBrush}" 
                            Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}" />
                    <Border x:Name="ReadonlyBorder" 
                            Visibility="Collapsed" 
                            Background="Transparent" 
                            BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}" 
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                            Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}" />
                    <Border Background="Transparent" 
                            BorderThickness="1" 
                            BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneDarkBorderBrush}" 
                            Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}">
                        <ContentControl x:Name="ContentElement" 
                                        BorderThickness="0"
                                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                                        VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                                        Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxInnerMargin}"/>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
```

However, all this seems to do is *always* apply the border thickness of 1, it never changes to 4. I can't understand why - can anyone give me a clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the BorderThickness to 4 on Unfocused, but the UnfocusedBorder element is missing the TemplateBinding and is hardcoded to 1. So add BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" to "UnfocusedBorder".

```
<DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="4" />

<Border x:Name="UnfocusedBorder"
       Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
       BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
       BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneDarkBorderBrush}" 
       Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}" />
```